# Unable to install "screen" package python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've been developing python applications on ubuntu.
I always work in a virtualenv for better package handling.
I recently cloned my project on windows, created a virtualenv.
Ran

> pip install -r requirements.txt

**requirements.txt**

> certifi==2018.11.29
>
> chardet==3.0.4
>
> dj-database-url==0.5.0
>
> Django==2.1.2
>
> django-admin==1.3.2
>
> django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
>
> django-excel-response2==2.0.8
>
> django-extensions==2.1.4
>
> django-filter==2.0.0
>
> django-heroku==0.3.1
>
> djangorestframework==3.9.0
>
> flake8==3.6.0
>
> gunicorn==19.9.0
>
> httpie==1.0.2
>
> idna==2.8
>
> jedi==0.13.2
>
> mccabe==0.6.1
>
> parso==0.3.1
>
> pep8==1.7.1
>
> Pillow==5.3.0
>
> psycopg2==2.7.5
>
> psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
>
> pycodestyle==2.4.0
>
> pydotplus==2.0.2
>
> pyflakes==2.0.0
>
> Pygments==2.3.1
>
> pyparsing==2.3.0
>
> pytz==2018.5
>
> requests==2.21.0
>
> taggit-selectize==2.6.0
>
> urllib3==1.24.1
>
> whitenoise==4.1.1
>
> xlwt==1.3.0

Also installed C++ build tools, but couldn't install a dependency of a package called "screen".

> Python version: 3.7.2
>
> pip version: 19.0.2
>
> setup tools version: 40.8.0

**Full trace:**

> PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Crowdsocial> pip install -r .\requirements.txt
>   Requirement already satisfied: certifi==2018.11.29 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 1)) (2018.11.29)
>   Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.0.4 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url==0.5.0 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.5.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: Django==2.1.2 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.1.2)
>   Collecting django-admin==1.3.2 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 5))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/69/c3fea1bb60e45f52bcc658cae6f04a25cbf8c7e8b3257f90dfd77575214b/django_admin-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.7.2 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 6))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/05/6bad05742d185ec2fabfa4deab05cafde286eb3f383fba24b3674340aca2/django_crispy_forms-1.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting django-excel-response2==2.0.8 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 7))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/ca/1917052aa5101b6511b997d8d71da020b200cf155abe5b3510e3ee5d5a85/django_excel_response2-2.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting django-extensions==2.1.4 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 8))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/56/6a854a56732f7cb6a0393b8a32ae8a37b82b004e638b7b2f153b66733ce5/django_extensions-2.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting django-filter==2.0.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 9))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/8b/8517167a0adc45ce94d0873efb9487dd4cdeff7e10f96e837ad3d58f5837/django_filter-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 10))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting djangorestframework==3.9.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 11))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/0b/d37a5a96c5d301e23adcabcc2f3fa659fb34e6308590f95ebb50cdbe98a1/djangorestframework-3.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting flake8==3.6.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 12))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/a6/49e2849a0e5464e1b5d621f63bc8453066f0f367bb3b744a33fca0bc1ddd/flake8-3.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 13))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting httpie==1.0.2 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 14))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/46/cfb014b9de6ac5cdd1fa06d85f411dd9506102c8b094906460b4a1710681/httpie-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting idna==2.8 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 15))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting jedi==0.13.2 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 16))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/bc/54d53f5bc4658380d0eca9055d72be4df45e5bfd91a4bac97da224a92553/jedi-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: mccabe==0.6.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 17)) (0.6.1)
>   Collecting parso==0.3.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 18))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/51/9c48a46334be50c13d25a3afe55fa05c445699304c5ad32619de953a2305/parso-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pep8==1.7.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 19))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/3f/669429ce58de2c22d8d2c542752e137ec4b9885fff398d3eceb1a7f5acb4/pep8-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting Pillow==5.3.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 20))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/49/e9de895c7baab95f9b3ab6c8df272edcabba3c92046b008cfa4650fe6eea/Pillow-5.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   Collecting psycopg2==2.7.5 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 21))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/89/9bbcc4ab312be0e32abd268512fce75f13a015c4c6a6340b600d168f0dbd/psycopg2-2.7.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 22))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/a1/5c2ed2c56296963cfc9f506bd7ce3a520f906f9404359f1b3fecac7f2fd8/psycopg2_binary-2.7.6.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
>   Collecting pycodestyle==2.4.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 23))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/c6/ce130213489969aa58610042dff1d908c25c731c9575af6935c2dfad03aa/pycodestyle-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pydotplus==2.0.2 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 24))
>   Collecting pyflakes==2.0.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 25))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/98/af7a72c9a543b1487d92813c648cb9b9adfbc96faef5455d60f4439aa99b/pyflakes-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting Pygments==2.3.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 26))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/e5/6d710c9cf96c31ac82657bcfb441df328b22df8564d58d0c4cd62612674c/Pygments-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting pyparsing==2.3.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 27))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e8/6777f6624681c8b9701a8a0a5654f3eb56919a01a78e12bf3c73f5a3c714/pyparsing-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2018.5 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 28)) (2018.5)
>   Collecting requests==2.21.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 29))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/e3/20f3d364d6c8e5d2353c72a67778eb189176f08e873c9900e10c0287b84b/requests-2.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting taggit-selectize==2.6.0 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 30))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/5a/7d45601f587cbfa6e4135ae6a486ce8d2981e516bfff7f8227ea249c4b55/taggit_selectize-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting urllib3==1.24.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 31))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/00/ee1d7de624db8ba7090d1226aebefab96a2c71cd5cfa7629d6ad3f61b79e/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting whitenoise==4.1.1 (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 32))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/0e/9a2c44be678a998ddb96d872b5c1e5bc1db3f3c2b12dcf5d129a7c2f4cbf/whitenoise-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Requirement already satisfied: xlwt==1.3.0 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from -r .\requirements.txt (line 33)) (1.3.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: django-six>=1.0.4 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from django-excel-response2==2.0.8->-r .\requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.0.4)
>   Collecting screen (from django-excel-response2==2.0.8->-r .\requirements.txt (line 7))
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/d2/68dacd66f28618462650e475f29663eb1f97cecdc3cf8f0881e52f425a3a/screen-1.0.1.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from django-extensions==2.1.4->-r .\requirements.txt (line 8)) (1.12.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=30 in c:\python3\lib\site-packages (from flake8==3.6.0->-r .\requirements.txt (line 12)) (40.8.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.2.4; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\hp\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from httpie==1.0.2->-r .\requirements.txt (line 14)) (0.4.1)
>   Installing collected packages: screen, django-excel-response2, django-admin, django-crispy-forms, django-extensions, django-filter, psycopg2, whitenoise, django-heroku, djangorestframework, pyflakes, pycodestyle, flake8, gunicorn, Pygments, urllib3, idna, requests, httpie, parso, jedi, pep8, Pillow, psycopg2-binary, pyparsing, pydotplus, taggit-selectize
>     Running setup.py install for screen ... error
>       Complete output from command c:\users\hp\desktop\crowdsocial\venv_windows\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f890mboe\screen\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5lhghcc6\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.7\screen
>       copying screen\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\screen
>       copying screen\old_str_util.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\screen
>       copying screen__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\screen
>       running build_ext
>       building 'screen.str_util' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

```
----------------------------------------
```

> Command
>   "c:\users\hp\desktop\crowdsocial\venv_windows\scripts\python.exe -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f890mboe\screen\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5lhghcc6\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f890mboe\screen\

Answer (score 0):

You should read error message first:

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":

Comment: You should check the answer first, I mentioned that I already installed it.

Comment: Great. Now go convince pip.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think you should read his question again